# Monitor Amazon SQS delayed processing

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have a series of applications that consume messages from SQS Queues. If for some reason one of these consumers fails and stop consuming messages I'd like to be notified. What's the best way to do this?

Note that some of these queues could only have one message placed into the queue every 2 - 3 days, so waiting for the # of messages in the queue to trigger a notification is not a good option for me.

What I'm looking for is something that can monitor an SQS queue and say "This message has been here for an hour and nothing has processed it ... let someone know."

Comment: I assume the required solution may rely on other AWS services. 
To track what you have described you can use Amazon CloudWatch service, which allows you to track the state of the SQS queue. Check out the documentation for that. 
Different question is how to implement the tracking without setting alarms on the CloudWatch. If you are okay with allowing 1 hour delay after the service failure, u can set up an hourly lambda function on AWS to do the tracking and notification for you. You might as well develop you own solution as a cronjob monitoring

Comment: The cloudwatch service does not seem to have a counter that would suite my needs. Perhaps I'm just missing it? The Lambda idea is an interesting one .. I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: I have a number of questions that would guide what the best solution would be.  How often are you polling the queue?  Are you using long polling and polling constantly ( that seems a little excessive given your message volume) or just polling every few hours?  How long does it take to process a message?  Are you more interested in monitoring the messages in the queue or the application that is consuming messages from the queue?

Comment: My application is pushing messages into an SNS Topic which then has multiple SQS Subscribers. There are then multiple consumers .. Department X could be responsible for consuming from Queue A and Department Y could be responsible for consuming from Queue B. As a rule of thumb we don't want a message to be in the SQS  Queue for more than say 10 minutes. If it has been in the Queue for more than 10 minutes either the consumer is not processing anymore for some reason ... or it can't keep up. What I 'm trying to do is create an Alert system that tells me that either of these two cases is presnt.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution off the top of my head (possibly not the most elegant one) which does not require using CloudWatch at all (according to the comment from OP the required tracking cannot be implemented through CloudWatch alarms). Assume you have the Queue to be processed at Service and the receiving side is implemented through long polling. 
Run a Lambda function (say hourly) listening to the Queue and reading messages, however never deleting (Service deletes the messages once processed). On the Queue set the Maximum Receives to any value u want, let's say 3. If Lambda function ran 3 times and all three times message was present in the queue, the message will be pushed to Dead Letter Queue (automatically if the redrive policy is set). Whenever new message is pushed to dead letter queue, it is a good indicator that your service is either down or not handling the requests fast enough. All variables can be changed to suit your needs